# How can I load or run multiple SQL files in Datagrip?

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

I have set up a project in DataGrip with several sql files spread over a couple of directories like this: [image: Project File Structure]

My hope is to manage the complexity as this turns into hundreds of files.  This is a learning/proof of concept level effort right now.

What I want to do is have a way to run/build/publish this project but at present the best I have found is to select the files and then do a "Run Files" CTRL+SHIFT+F10.  This worked for a bit but now I have a foreign key that gets run in the wrong order.  I don't want to have to make a hack like prefixing the file names with integers to force a specific order.  It feels like a real kludge.

How should I accomplish this, I must have missed something since the alternative is very manual and error prone.  If it matters the database I am working against is Oracle.

Comment: Hello! What actually you want to have? Some model where you can clarify the order of files to run?

Comment: @moscas Something like that, back under Visual Studio we had a similar layout and had a master SQL file that listed the other files and the order to load them.  At the end of the day I want be be able to say, load all of these files as a set and control the order so that constraints are honored.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Please, share your additional ideas in the created issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4473

Answer (score 8):

Since DataGrip 2020.1 one can create a *Run Configuration* and specify data source and multiple files or scripts:

[image: run configuration set up]

Refer to [DataGrip blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2020/02/27/we-open-eap-for-datagrip-2020-1/).