# Can I create a run configuration for an SQL file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

My program generates SQL files. In IntelliJ IDEA, with my database connected, I can run a .sql file as [documented here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-sql-script-files.html). However, it seems I cannot add a run configuration that performs that exact run for me. Is there a way?

Comment: There is no [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) for sql file run. Why would you need one?

Comment: *Need* is a big word, but it would be easier to add the run configuration to a pipeline of IntelliJ IDEA tasks that I now have to run manually. Running all the thing one after another can become tedious, and some tasks take time and therefore require some attention before the next task can be started.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. There is a related feature request, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4473 and you are very welcome to leave your feedback there. Btw similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43379267/2000323